# Does the word "man" mean "a male friend"?

Tags: word-meaning

I found on [WordReference.com Dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/man) that the word **man** means **a male friend**!

> 8. (Slang Terms) male friend; ally:
>    *Hey, it's my main man.*

I looked in many dictionaries e.g. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/man), [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/man), and [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/man) and I didn't find that the word **man** means **a male friend**.

Can somebody who has English language as their native language tell me whether that is correct?

Comment: Are you implying that strangers on the internet have a degree of credibility that the compilers of a dictionary lack?

Comment: As links become stale, change over time or get paywalled, you should maybe quote the definition from WordReference directly by copying it into the question.

Comment: Note that the phrase you're quoting is "main man", and you shouldn't extend any interpretation of it to "man" out of context. Put another way, if "learned friend" denotes a lawyer it's inappropriate to assume that all friends are lawyers.

Comment: One possible use of this meaning: [batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(military)).  Also it's used in this sense when playing (some board and) video games.  Your 'man' is the token or ship or 'life' that fights on your side - so I'd say that the most arguable bit about the definition is not that they are a friend or ally, but are male.  A comment like 'I'm on my last man so I can't take risks' would be valid when referring to Space Invaders, Qix or even Ms Pac-man

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Word Reference gives that meaning as the **eighth** definition and labels it **slang**. So, it would be more accurate to say that 'man' **can sometimes** be used to mean 'friend or ally', particularly in the phrase [main man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/main%20man).

Comment: There are a lot of related senses, such as man=soldier (which could include a fellow soldier or anyone who has your back), and "[the man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20man)"=someone praiseworthy or who you look up to. "He's my man" might be used in slang to mean "he's my friend/someone I trust".

Comment: (Sighs) Yes, English is my native language.

Comment: Whether English is @KateBunting 's native language does not seem relevant.  She simply looked at the dictionary that *you* cited, and reported on what she found. You don't need to be a  native speaker to do that.

Comment: This is the right answer. (I am a US-English native speaker.)

What's making this a challenging question is that your citations are _definition 8_ and _definition 14_ and labeled "slang" both times. High numbered definitions are generally less frequently used than the first few and come with usage caveats. Slang, likewise, always has usage caveats.

I think these meanings _are_ valid. The example of "main man" _can_ mean  "most significant male friend/ally/compatriot", but as a language-learner, you should be _very_ cautious in using slang when more-common meanings don't match your intent.

Comment: Marios, as a 70+ woman I'm not really qualified to answer a question about the usage of _bro_, which is mainly a young man's expression.

Answer (score 33):

Only in a couple of very specific contexts, perhaps.

"*My man*" is a (possibly dated) way of a male referring to another male friend, particularly a 'best friend', a bit like calling someone "*bro*".

A woman referring to "*my man*" would probably be taken to mean their husband, boyfriend or partner. Likewise, a woman saying she has "a man" could also be interpreted as them having a male companion, possibly a romantic relationship or in the early stages of one. See also expressions like "*gentleman friend*".

There may be other contexts. But I wouldn't expect either of these to be in dictionaries as they are either slang or the meaning is subtly implied.

Comment: Is English language your native language? So, the word man means a male friend and dictionaries don't say that because that meaning is implied! Am I correct?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Yes, I'm a native British English speaker. And I'm not saying dictionaries don't include them - you said you looked and couldn't find them! I just said I wasn't surprised. It's hard to explain as these aren't strictly alternative definitions, just alternate *uses*. Whatever else may be implied, they are all men in the sense of the dictionary definition. Another British use is when someone says something like "*I'm getting a man to look at my leaky roof*", they mean a tradesperson, but it's still a man!

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou, the Collins entry you linked to has definition 6: "If you say that a man is someone's man, you mean that he always supports that person or does what they want." And definition 16: "see *my man*". These are the meanings that WordReference is probably saying mean the word indicates friendship. (although #6 has some alternate meanings as well)

Comment: @ThePhoton: that definition 6 sounds much more like a servant or employee than a friend.

Comment: "If you need someone to drive the golf cart, I'm your man."

Comment: "Joseph, my man! Good to see you!"

Comment: @ColinFine, as I said,  #6 has some alternate meanings as well.

Comment: "My man" could also be your drug dealer, as in ["*I'm waiting for my man*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99og_g7rXnA).

Comment: Note that "my man" in paragraph two and "my man" in paragraph three would have very different sounds (mostly stress, less so pronunciation), at least in North American English.

Comment: You da man! <padding/>

Comment: I think in all of these examples it is the possessive pronoun, not the noun, that is doing the work of indicating friendship (or whatever else the relationship may be based on context).

Comment: @ColinFine "my man" can also mean a sycophant or underling who is dependent on you.

Comment: @masher or a valet, footman etc., i.e. an employed attendant.

Comment: @Astralbee There's a comic bit about getting a man to look at the roof (or the plumbing or something similar) and it turns out the man is a woman. "When you said you had a man for this..." Would broadly recommend new speakers to use gender neutral language for times when the gender makes no difference, it's just as easy to say you're getting "someone" to look at the roof.

Comment: @Astralbee The women's words sound entirely correct but in 60-odd years of listening I've never heard, nor read in print or seen on screen anyone using 'My man' to refer to anyone as any kind of friend, let alone a 'best friend'.

An acquaintance or colleague, servant or supplier perhaps but do you really rank any of those as 'friends'? 

'My man' is indeed very much like 'bro' and I suggest neither means 'friend'; rather, both mean something like 'someone I recognise and (prolly) respect.' Whatever it actually means, I don't see how 'my man' is 'dated'.

Answer (score 23):

I am a native English speaker.

I think your confusion here is that you believe "man" must either *always* be able to mean "male friend" (so it should always be in the dictionary) or on the other hand it must *never* be able to mean "male friend" (so it should never be in the dictionary).

The real answer is that "man" only rarely means "male friend", and only in select kinds of usages, because **it is slang**.

**The first thing to recognize is that not all slang is created equal.** Some slang is so common that it just becomes a part of the language. Other slang only sees niche usage in limited contexts (think internet slang or memes). Some slang *used* to be popular a hundred years ago and isn't popular now, so a dictionary might choose to remove it even if they did have it once.

**The second thing to recognize is that dictionaries differ in their approach to what words they include.** Some dictionaries prefer to be very rigorous and only include words that have very well supported citations and see relatively broad use. At the other end of the spectrum, some dictionaries are happy to include anything people want to add (think Urban Dictionary).

**Finally, let's talk about when "man" can mean "male friend"**. The word "man" by itself would not mean to me, as an English speaker, "male friend". However if I were talking to a guy and he said something like, "Oh Richard? Yo, Richard is my man!" or "Oh Richard? Richard is my boy!", I would understand either of those to be slang implying that they are pretty close friends.

Here are some examples where "man" does *not* mean "male friend":

- She bought a coat from the man.
- The man listened to the radio broadcast thoughtfully.
- "I want to find a man" she said.
- "That was an amazing throw - you're the man!"
- The law says you gotta pay taxes to the Man.
- A man must provide for his family.
- "I have to see a man about a horse."
- "Son, I want you to grow up to be a better man than me."
- She said "Jacob is my man and I love him."

For that last one, when "man" is said by a girl in this way, it is most likely slang for "boyfriend".

And here are some examples where "man" does mean "male friend":

- He greeted his friend with a fist bump, "My man!"
- The guy gestured at his friend, "My man Jake is crazy good at guitar."
- "Oh, you know Richard? Richard is my man!" said the guy.
- "Doug here is my main man" said the male actor in the 70's film, probably, about his friend.
- "What's up man? It's good to see you."
- "Hey man, can I get a light?" he said, gesturing with his cigarette.

I hope this helps explain the limited scope of the slang.

Comment: Nice answer, man. But man, it feels like you're commenting on a compound term "my man" here, rather than on "man". Man, this answer sure could be improved by some senses of man which don't need "my" to mean friend. Thanks, man. (comparable do "dude" or "bro" or "mate", or "pal", etc)

Comment: @DewiMorgan The source cited in the question does only give a "my man"-example as well. And it is the *eighth* meaning, and marked as slang.. Not really a strong claim to warrant further investigation.

Comment: As you say, it is not black and white. As strange and complex as English is, I'm always a little confused when people ask questions like this one about English. Do other languages not have slang that works this way?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I find myself wondering the same thing regularly. I know a language in which words used for "guy" or "man" include a word that may mean a castrated animal. Another castrated animal somehow became a (now archaic) endearing term for a child. 
Then again, in both cases, very few native speakers of that language realize that when using those words - the latter appears even in a popular seasonal children's song.

Comment: @DewiMorgan that's good feedback - I shall shamelessly steal your example :P No worries, I got you man

Comment: Still at issue is whether or not *my man* means *my friend*.  I have heard the phrased used for decades but until reading this question on ELL, I would never have considered it to mean *friend*.  How many *main men* can one person have?  Can a group be introduced as *my main men*?   Does *my man* mean *my **best** friend*?  A boss might say, *See my man, Dave, about this.*  Is Dave his friend or is Dave the guy who gets *it* done?

Comment: @EllieK Now look here, my good man... huh, you're right, and if we insert "good" I guess it can also mean "definitely-not-friend, person I am at odds with".

Comment: Where does 'always or never' come into this in particular, any more than the meaning of many another term?

Comment: By the way, most of your examples where 'man' does mean 'male friend', in fact don't.
 
A greeting with a fist bump, "My man!" applies equally to a welcome stranger. Your meaning comes solely from the phrase 'greeted his friend', as does "My man Jake…"

"Richard is my man" has no clear meaning, nor do your actor's "Doug here is my main man" nor "What's up man? It's good to see you" nor "Hey man, can I get a light?"

All those phrases might be used of friends; none of them clearly or specifically applies to friends.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The OP implied that if dictionaries have different definitions listed for a word, then some of the dictionaries must be wrong and some of them must be right. I was trying to make the point that words don't always carry some of their meanings, which are only valid with certain context. So "man" does not always mean "male friend", and if a dictionary chooses not to have a rarer meaning, that doesn't make the dictionary wrong (or vice versa).

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I would argue that the term "friend" doesn't always mean one with whom you have a close, long-term relationship, as you imply. "Hey man, can I get a light?" has about the same meaning as, "My friend, can I get a light?", which is definitely a valid use of the word "friend".  Although, if you think this answer could be improved with a short discussion of the different meanings of the word "friend", I welcome any edits you would offer

Comment: That Answer could be improved by showing how the examples are usually, let alone always true, without relying on context. Why not try that? 

I assume Marios chose to Ask whether 'man' means 'male friend', particularly in the given context, from the point of view of a non-native speaker seeking clarity.

Of course 'friend' can be used loosely and if Marios had asked about that kind of complexity in SE English Langue Usage it might be worth discussing… and still the Answer would be 'it might, sometimes.'

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou just like "man", "bro" is slang and it _can_ mean "friend", but it doesn't always have to (it is short for "brother", and can mean literally a male sibling). I don't think there's much value in creating one question per English slang term. What is your REAL question?

Answer (score 9):

No, "man" does not mean "friend".

WordReference.com is not a reputable dictionary like the others you referenced. In my opinion, that definition does not deserve to be there.

The example they give, "*my man*", I believe is the only time "man" can be even loosely understood to mean "friend", so rather than give "friend" as a possible definition of "man", it makes more sense to define the idiomatic phrase, "*my man*", as [Oxford](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/113198;jsessionid=F4A6617CC0E70355C0D006E8783FB264) does:

> **man**
> **20. b.** Originally among African Americans.   **my man** *n*. a male person regarded with great respect or admiration; **a person's very close male friend**. Frequently as a form of address (**sometimes without connotation of close friendship**, as a merely familiar form of address between two males)

For instance:

> My man here just got me a job!

This would not indicate that the two are necessarily friends, just that the speaker is very happy that the other guy got him a job.

<sub>And yes, I'm a native speaker.</sub>

Comment: The dictionary is called: *WordReference Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English* © 2023. It appears that WR supplements the original reference, [see here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/wordreference-random-house-learners-dictionary-of-american-english.3263298/) for clarification

Comment: [Oxford English Dictionary **Def 20 b**. Originally among African Americans](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/113198;jsessionid=F4A6617CC0E70355C0D006E8783FB264).  **my man** n. a male person regarded with great respect or admiration; **a person's very close male friend**. Frequently as a form of address (sometimes without connotation of close friendship, as a merely familiar form of address between two males.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you! Added

Comment: `"my man", is the only time "man" can be even loosely understood to mean "friend"`
False. Counterexample: "Hey man, how's it going!"

Comment: @Brondahl Why do you think "man" means friend there? I can say "Hey man" to literally any male, friend or not.

Comment: Agreed. And _sometimes_ its use will be denoting a friendly relationships ... and other times it won't. I certainly agree with the broad point everyone is making that it doesn't *always* connote friendship. But _sometimes_ it does. Even without the "My" prefix.

Comment: I agree with Mari-LouA.  My man can be a *best friend* but my man is almost never used for *just a friend*.

Comment: @gotube It does mean friend there, even if the degree of friendship is very slight or maybe the person saying it is just being overly familiar. It's just like how I could say "hey buddy" to anyone, buddy unambiguously means friend, or "hey pal".

Comment: @user3067860 You only think it means "friend" because the context surrounding it seems friend-like, not because the word "man" *means* "friend". "Hey man, back off!" In that context, it clearly doesn't mean "friend", but it's the exact same expression.

Comment: @gotube I could also say, "Hey pal, back off!" or "Hey buddy, back off!" Are you saying pal and buddy don't mean friend? You're using it condescendingly which flips the meaning, but reinforces that it means friend when used sincerely. (Not like best friend, but in the same social bracket sort of friend.)

Comment: @user3067860 Those usages are similar, but my argument is that unlike pal, buddy, friend, mate, etc., "man" simply doesn't mean "friend" on its own. "Hey man" is closer to "Hey you", in that "you" doesn't mean "friend".

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou I saw your comment, but didn't feel like answering that question. You've been warned about repeatedly begging for upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

No.  'Man' means an adult, male, human being.  Or, sometimes, generically ALL humans.

It's only when qualified by a possessive that it can imply alliance or a (possibly sexual) partnership.  'Hey, man!' is an informal, neutral greeting.

'He's a man' is neutral.   'He's my man' implies a connection.

The only examples that comes to mind of 'man' being anything but neutral is 'He's a real man' or 'Act like a man!' which imply approval of masculine qualities.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to dive a bit into language history to explain that:

1. the germanic root "man"
   This root (the "a" is pronounced like in "father") means "(hu-)man". This is why a sentence like "man managed to fly to the moon" doesn't mean "male humans" but "the whole of *homo sapiens*". When germanic languages evolved and related languages like German and English started to differentiate English retained the original meaning but also added a second meaning, that of "male human". In German the original meaning was preserved in the word "man" (like in "man sagt" - "it is being said") and created the word "Mann" ("man" as in "male human") for the second meaning.
2. "man"/"husband", "woman"/"wife"
   Also notice that originally words amounting to "man" and "woman" were used also meaning "husband" and "wife". The english word "wife" comes in fact from a germanic word "wif" meaning "woman". In i.e. German this word has survived as "Weib", an old word for "woman" (nota bene, not "wife", but just "female human"). "woman" comes - via "wifman" - from exactly this word. That "wife" originally was just "woman", not necessarily "married woman" can be seen in words like "midwife", "old wives' tale" or "housewife".
3. being married
   The concept of being married - that is, having entered a formally binding contract - instead of being just partners is historically relatively young, surely younger than the invention of some basic language concepts. This is why "my man" *can* mean something similar to (or even exactly) "my husband", especially if said by a female. Again comparing that with a closely related language like german: "mein Mann"/"meine Frau" means exactly "my husband"/"my wife" even though "Mann" means "man" and "Frau" means "woman". It is possible but rather unusual to clarify that ("mein Ehemann", "meine Ehefrau", "Ehe" being "matrimony").

Answer (score 0):

Another common use of "man" as a friend is in the official term "best man", meaning originally someone's closest male friend, but now meaning "the man that stands behind the groom to assist him" during a marriage ceremony.  In western Christian marriage ceremonies, the "best man" duties include safely transporting the wedding ring to the ceremony and handing it to the groom just before the groom puts the wedding ring on the bride's finger, but the best man has many other duties during the event depending on local traditions, though fundamentally, the "best man" helps and protects the groom throughout the day.  In some Germanic languages, this meaning of a "best man" has other titles.

Beware that in military and other hierarchical contexts, a leader's "best man" is the best (most capable and most trusted) of the men under that leader's command.

Comment: If those church, military or other hierarchical contexts were clearly historically correct I'd still be asking why 'main man' and 'best man' aren't usually interchangeable, even if we ignored mere 'man'…